# Problemas ao calcular em média em Java

Tags: java, ponto-flutuante

Estou tentando fazer um programa que calcule a média entre 4 valores.

Código:

```
    private void botao1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText());
    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(txt2.getText());
    int n3 = Integer.parseInt(txt3.getText());
    int n4 = Integer.parseInt(txt4.getText());
    float notaf = (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4;
    res.setText(Float.toString(notaf));
}
```

O problema é que quando eu tendo usar o resultado da média (notaf) ele sempre vem como um número inteiro (7.0, 8.0, 3.0) e não vem com os números decimais (7.5, 8.5, 3.5) onde eu errei?

Print do programa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(A média nesse caso deveria ser 6,75)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pergunta já responde onde está o problema. Note que as 4 notas são do tipo `int`. Este tipo, como o próprio nome indica, só aceita números inteiros. Tem que trocar o tipo das variáveis, e consequentemente das conversões. No caso deve usar o [`float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) (dá para se discutir se este tipo também é adequado, mas vai resolver este exercício).

```
private void botao1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    float n1 = Float.parseFloat(txt1.getText());
    float n2 = Float.parseFloat(txt2.getText());
    float n3 = Float.parseFloat(txt3.getText());
    float n4 = Float.parseFloat(txt4.getText());
    float notaf = (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4;
    res.setText(Float.toString(notaf));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/r4Jpng). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hclbxysl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/ParseFloat.java).

Answer (score 4):

O seu problema é que todas as variáveis são do tipo `int`. Se fizer operações só com inteiros, o resultado também é inteiro, sempre ignorando(note, ele ignora e não arredonda!) a parte decimal.

Se você fizer `float notaf = (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4f;`, pra dizer que o operador é `float` já seria o suficiente pra funcionar como você quer.